# Ajax actions are incremented within MVC partial, why is this?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I'm working through some bugs in an application I'm working on and noticed some interesting behaviour. I have a partial view on a page that contains just one Ajax.BeginForm. At one point in the application I wanted to call an action right after the ajax action was done so I went ahead and called,

```
$(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
    // Do task here
});
```

I noticed however on subsequent ajax calls that ajaxComplete was being called multiple times. So I setup a test case to try and reproduce the error. After setting this up in the **main view**,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        console.log("Main View : " + (++counter));
    });
});
```

And this up in the **partial view**,

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var counter = 0;

    $(document).ajaxComplete(function () {
        console.log("Partial View : " + (++counter));
    });
});
```

I got this console output on multiple calls,

```
// Ajax.BeginForm Submit action 1
Main View : 1
Partial View : 1
// Ajax.BeginForm Submit action 2
Main View : 2
Partial View : 2
Partial View : 1
// Ajax.BeginForm Submit action 3
Main View : 3
Partial View : 3
Partial View : 2
Partial View : 1
// Ajax.BeginForm Submit action 4
Main View : 4
Partial View : 4
Partial View : 3
Partial View : 2
Partial View : 1
```

What I can't figure out is why this is happening. Is my Ajax begin form firing multiple times in my partial or is it just that I am creating duplicate listeners for ajax complete? I'm worried about the implications this might have for other places within my application.

Comment: Read the documentation about the function and it will explain when it is being called and what you should use =]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are registering a new callback for your `ajaxComplete` event in your partial view. So every time you submit your form which returns this partial view, this code will be registered again and again ! That is the reason you are seeing the log message from partial view multiple times.

You should register your `ajaxComplete` only once in your main view so that it gets executed only once.

Comment: I suspected something like this might be the case but wasn't ultimately sure. So then is it ok for me to have the AjaxBeginForm in the partial? Or do I just need to make sure that any script listeners are placed up in the main view?

Comment: you should keep the code which binds to any events in the script which loads in the main view (only once)